# Where to find mysql logs regarding user changes in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, logging, phpmyadmin

I want to know, is there a log that saves all the changes made by users to a database just like in git where all the commits can be viewed by each user so that if any error occur we know who did it.If there is one how to get it? or how to create one that will do it?
Problem I'm facing is that a table's data has been altered by one of the developers but there is no way to find when and who did it and also I am struggling to find all the changes that has been done to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases typically do not provide auditing as standard. I typically implement it within my application. However, for a faster result, there are some [plugins](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-simple-easy-to-use-PHP-MySQL-Audit-Log-to-comply-with-data-privacy-requirements) for mySQL which you could try.

Comment: Oh now i see why people don't use it much. DB's performance will reduce 10% - 30% if these auditing plugins were used. I don't want to reduce the performance. But thanks for the answer.